# jQuery post data from <a> link

Tags: html, jquery, post, http-post, jquery-ui-autocomplete

EDIT: I found the answer to my question here: [Send AJAX request by clicking a link without redirecting user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623019/send-ajax-request-by-clicking-a-link-without-redirecting-user)

Hi I'm making a jQuery autocomplete menu with a fixed item at the bottom that is not connected to the select event for the other menu items. The fixed item needs to post data that is in the search box of  autocomplete menu, "this.term".

This is the code I have, but it is not firing.

```
      var render = $('#findBook').autocomplete('instance')._renderMenu;

        $('#findBook').autocomplete('instance')._renderMenu = function(ul, items) {


            $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderMenu.apply( this, [ul, items] );
            ul.append( '<li><a onClick="postdata()" id=this.term>See all results: '+ this.term + '</a></li>' );

            function postdata(){

                    $.post("/book_profile/" + id);


            };
        };
```

Comment: Any console errors?  What is the scope of this logic?  How is it invoked?

Comment: I don't have console errors, but I edited the code so you can see it is contained within code to add a fixed item to the autocomplete menu.

Comment: `postdata` is declared inside another method, so it is not in the global scope.  Only methods accessable off of the global scope in some manner are usable for inline bindings.